# systemd.service "Conflicts=" only cares about "running" services not "active" ones. Any workarround

Tags: systemd

## Setup

I have two services that are basically complementary.

Service A (gdm) is a daemon; Service B only triggers a small `ExecStart=` and `ExecStop=`

```
service-b-hdmi.service
-------------------------
[Unit]
Description=Turn off HDMI
Conflicts=gdm.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c '/bin/echo off > /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/status'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/bash -c '/bin/echo on > /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/status'
```

## Start condition

- Service A (gdm) is **stopped**
- Service B (HDMI) is **started** "active (exited)" (turning off the hdmi card)

## Issue

- Starting Service A (gdm) should stop service B as both are in conflict.
- However, Service B lives happily and now both services are active. Service A is "active (running)" and Service B is "active (exited)"

## Question

Is there any way to enforce the `Conflicts=`

Comment: It may take some time for `HDMI.service` to exit, some suggestions, not sure if they solve your problem:.
  Try to configure `Conflicts=HDMI.service` in the `gdm.service` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=) say this:

> If a unit has a `Conflicts=` setting on another unit, starting the
> former will stop the latter and vice versa.

So, if 'service-b-hdmi.service' contains `Conflicts=gdm.service`, starting 'service-b-hdmi.service' will cause 'gdm.service' to be stopped.

To make this work in the reverse direction - which is where you seem to be facing the problem - you'll need a `Conflicts=service-b-hdmi.service` in the unit file for 'gdm.service'. Then, starting 'gdm.service' will cause the 'service-b-hdmi.service' to be stopped, which seems to be the expected behaviour.

The documentation also suggests using `After=` or `Before=` to enforce ordering - making sure that one unit is fully shut down before the other one starts up. The ordering logic is slightly complex when both units are starting up or shutting down. In this case, however, one unit is shutting down and the other unit is starting up. `systemd` schedules all shutdown jobs before startup jobs, so in this scenario, both `Before=` and `After=` have the same effect. Again, you'll need to set the property on both unit files.

Comment: you are right, however, i would say the documentation says exactly that this is not needed because `Conflicts=` also acts on the "vise-versa" direction. meaning it *should* be symmetric.

After using `systemctl edit gdm.service` and adding the reverse conflict. The service is properly killed. Really strange wording in the documentation.

Comment: About the `After=`: What do you mean with "job". So far i understood `After=` and `Before=` as only relevant for starting services. Meaning if Service A after Service B, the starting of service A is held back until Service A has finished starting.

Comment: @StefanHeid Right, the 'vice versa' part sounds a little vague to me as well. The ordering logic with Before/After is explained here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before= . It's a little too long to cover in a comment.